# SQL: sub selects with dates

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have this SQL:

```
Select history.date, history.rasID, status.status
From RAS_RASHistory as history
inner join RAS_Status as status on History.statusID = status.statusID
Where history.date between @startDate 
      and @endDate and history.statusID in (select value from @status)
order by rasID, history.date desc
```

When I execute it, I get these results:

```
date                    rasID   status
2011-11-17 14:15:21.693 10000   Planning
2011-11-17 14:14:53.177 10000   New
2011-11-16 08:39:47.770 10000   New
2011-11-16 09:18:50.630 10001   New
2011-11-16 11:26:23.867 10002   Planning
2011-11-16 10:01:42.050 10002   Planning
2011-11-16 10:00:36.527 10002   New
```

What I really want is this:

```
date                    rasID   status
2011-11-17 14:15:21.693 10000   Planning
2011-11-16 09:18:50.630 10001   New
2011-11-16 11:26:23.867 10002   Planning
```

But I am not sure exactly how to go about getting it.  I think a subselect might be the way, but I'm not quite sure.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So get the latest date for each `rasID` and then fetch the latest `status`

Comment: Need to formulate the requirement better. For each rasId entry you want the most recent status. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I want the most recent status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  Select h.[date], h.rasID, s.[status], -- please pick better column names!
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.rasID ORDER BY h.[date] DESC)
  FROM dbo.RAS_RASHistory as h -- please use dbo prefix!
  INNER JOIN dbo.RAS_Status as s -- please use manageable aliases!
  ON h.statusID = s.statusID
  Where h.date between @startDate and @endDate 
  and h.statusID in (select value from @status)
)
SELECT [date], rasID, [status]
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
order by rasID, [date] desc;
```

[Also please be very careful about `BETWEEN` for date ranges](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

You could also re-write this as:

```
;WITH h AS
(
  SELECT [date], rasID, statusID,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rasID ORDER BY [date] DESC
  FROM dbo.RAS_RASHistory
  WHERE [date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  AND statusID IN (SELECT value FROM @status)
)
SELECT h.[date], h.rasID, s.[status]
   FROM h INNER JOIN dbo.RAS_Status AS s
   ON h.statusID = s.StatusID
   AND h.rn = 1
ORDER BY h.rasID, h.[date] DESC;
```

Comment: Why the brackets around date?  Just curious.

Comment: @Michael because it's a keyword in SQL Server (`date` is a data type), and if you don't enclose it in square brackets, it lights up blue in Management Studio. In the future it may become a reserved word and, aside from the unnecessary coloring, enclosing it aids in future-proofing. The best solution, of course, is to not use a keyword as a vague identifier (`date` of WHAT?) in the first place.

Comment: Alas, I did not create the database in question, but I'll keep that in mind when I do make one.  Thanks for the info.